# FindItemWithText in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I want to find a text in list view then remove it I could achieve it with winforms but looks difficult with WPF here's my code :

```
listView1.FindItemWithText("my text", true, 0).Remove();
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What did you set the ItemsSource property of your ListView to or what kind of items did you add to its Items collection?

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to write such function. Just iterate ListViewItems and delete it.

```
var str = "my text";
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
        if (item.Content.Equals(str))
        {
            //... do your stuff
        }
}
```

Comment: Deleting the item inside this loop will modify the collection being enumerated and will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could use linq

```
ListViewItem item = listView1.Items.Where(x => x.Content.ToString() == str).ToList()[0];
```

Comment: Alternatively, `ListViewItem item = listView1.Items.First(x => x.Content.ToString() == str);`